# For this particular motherboard where are the address and data lines (circuit traces) connecting the RAM to the CPU?

Tags: memory, motherboard, bus

This motherboard from an Acer Laptop was given to me by someone I work with who knows I've been getting interested in computers. You can see the two RAM slots but I can't for the life of me figure out where the address and memory buses connecting these to the CPU are. Any help is appreciated.

[image: Acer Laptop Motherboard]

Comment: Somewhere on layers 2 through n-1 on a n-layer PCB.

Comment: Sorry I'm still new at computers. So you're saying they're buried under the motherboard and therefore not visible?

Comment: They're routed on one of the inside layers of the motherboard. It is not strange for a x86 motherboard to have 6, 8, or even 10 layers.

Comment: ok thanks for responding. So they're just not on the surface then, right?

Comment: Not for very long, usually. The outer layers are usually ground, for RF/EMI purposes.